# Is it possible to have a wordpress filter without a corresponding function definition

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible that this statement can exist without a corresponding function definition for `woocommerce_rest_check_permissions`:

`apply_filters( 'woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', $permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type );`

I searched the WooCommerce codebase but couldn't find a corresponding function definition. I rather found four usage references all inside an `apply_filter` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is very common in WP plugins. The developers of the woocommerce plugin put these apply_filter statements in their code so that other developers(You) can modify the behavior of the plugin without having to alter the source code of the plugin itself.

You can checkout a list of all the hooks available in woocommerce here https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html